# How to fan out rows with a specified range of values?

Tags: postgresql, set-returning-functions

I have a table which essentially contains 3 columns: `ID`, `FIRST`, `LAST`. They're all integers.

I'm wondering if there's a way to use generate_series() to get a query result where for each row in the original table, there are many rows containing numbers between `FIRST` and `LAST`?

E.g. for a row with data `(42, 5, 8)` the output contains rows `(42, 5)`, `(42, 6)`, `(42, 7)` and `(42, 8)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postgres 10 or later it can be as simple as:

```
SELECT id, generate_series(first, last) AS nr
FROM   tbl;
```

In older versions it is not advisable to have set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list. See:

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in select clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39864815/939860)

Rows where `generate_series()` returns nothing are excluded from the result this way (e.g. when `last` < `first` or either is `NULL`). The same is true for the more explicit [`CROSS JOIN` syntax variant demonstrated by a_horse](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/221109/3684). May or may not be desirable. If it's not, use `LEFT JOIN .. ON true` instead:

```
SELECT t.id, g.nr
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL generate_series(t.first, t.last) g(nr) ON true;
```

(`LATERAL` is a noise word in this case, since it's assumed for *functions* in the `FROM` list.)

See:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2b59920ee72c1671aa54d08c0599ae2d)* (demonstrating corner cases)

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using `generate_series()`

```
with test_data (id, "first", "last") as (
   values (42, 5, 8), 
          (43, 6, 9)
)
select td.id, g.nr
from test_data td
  cross join lateral generate_series(td."first", td."last", 1) as g(nr)
order by td.id, g.nr;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/TWE47868